TargetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC]
Error message 1 :
Failed to start foreground service due to SecurityException - have you forgotten to request a permission? - Starting FGS with type dataSync callerApp=ProcessRecord{adb6e5 14637:com.nafdac.gov/u0a194} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC]
 App added permission : 
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.nafdac.gov">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICEDATA_SYNC"/> 


Your FOREGROUND_SERVICEDATA_SYNC should be FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC

As of Android 34 you need to declare the foreground service type in your manifest. See here for details
